# htaccess how to run all site pages to subdomain without changing the url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, prestashop

I want to redirect one site, but without changing the URL in the address bar.
Like: the URL is: `m.example.com` but here `example.com` should be run. And all the pages of the `example.com` should be run here.

e.g.
`m.example.com/about -> example.com/about`,
 but the URL in the address bar must be `m.example.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be achieved with some simple .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also you can read [this](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) great article on subject.